# Load MathJax On click of button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mathjax

I am pre-fetching the formula on the **html** with the hidden input value , I am using the **MathJax** script ,  on-load the MathJax started to trigger . But formula's are pref-etched on the html hidden tag , so I created button `..on-click` of the button formula's will be displayed on the html body . That process MathJax is not triggering on the JavaScript.

on-load of the page MathJax is executing , when i call on the JavaScript MathJax is triggering

I expect the output of `3/2` to be using MathJAx  3/2, but the actual output is `3/2`

```
window.MathJax = {
        "fast-preview": {
                disabled: true
        },
        AuthorInit: function() {
            MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook('End', function() {
                MathJax.Hub.processSectionDelay = 0
                var demoSource = document.getElementById('question_content')
                var demoRendering = document.getElementById('question_content')
                var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('question_content')[0]
                demoSource.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Text', math, demoSource.value])
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

I have used above code on load ... but it is not working on click of the button

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code that you have tried so that the community can help you

Comment: If you mean that you want to see a vertical fraction (a 3 on top of a 2 with a horizontal line in between), then `3/2` is not the correct markup for that.  MathJax will display this as `3/2`, but in the MathJax fonts.  To get a vertical fraction, you need to use `\frac{3}{2}` (provided you are using TeX input --- you don't actually say what MathJax configuration you are using).

Comment: Thanks Davide Cervone ... By the fraction method its working ...

Comment: If you mean that `\frac{3}{2}` is what you were looking for, we should make an actual answer that you can accept so that this question will be shown as answered.